# How to combine 2 queries in promql

Tags: promql

I have two queries in promql that I need join by instance so I can display the node name

first query : (1 - avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) by (instance))

first query result :

> {instance="10.103.20.68:9796"}
> 0.10527083333193621

second query : node_uname_info

second query result : `

> node_uname_info{container="node-exporter", domainname="(none)",
> endpoint="metrics", **instance**="10.103.20.68:9796",
> job="node-exporter", machine="x86_64",
> namespace="cattle-monitoring-system",
> **nodename**="iagindvd01-indv-dev-02-mastercentos3", pod="rancher-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter-pns4c",
> release="3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64",
> service="rancher-monitoring-prometheus-node-exporter",
> sysname="Linux", version="#1 SMP Wed Feb 23 16:47:03 UTC 2022"}

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to match both series based on their label sets using [`on`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching-keywords) and also [`group_left`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#group-modifiers) to make the `nodename` label from the right side available in the final result:

```
(1 - avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])))
* on (instance) group_left (nodename) node_uname_info
```